# Binding data to a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I've hit a roadblock with binding data to a `ComboBox`. I'm developing an app in Windows Phone 8.1 and simply all I want to do is list printers in the `ComboBox`.

This is my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxPrinters" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="153,150,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="237">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

This is the class that populates the list. The data is being returned as `Id|Name|Id|Name|Id|Name etc` which is why there is a `Split` and a `For[...]Next` statement. This bit of code does populate the class and adds them to the list. At the end I'm left with a list of 54 printers:

```
Public Class Printer

Public Id As Integer
Public Name As String

Public Function Populate(ByVal ResultString As String) As List(Of Printer)

    Dim _Results As List(Of String) = ResultString.Split(New String("|")).ToList

    Dim _Printers As New List(Of Printer)

    If _Results.Count >= 2 Then

        For i = 0 To _Results.Count - 1 Step 2
            Dim _Printer As New Printer

            With _Printer
                .Id = _Results(i)
                .Name = _Results(i + 1).Trim()
            End With

            _Printers.Add(_Printer)
        Next
    End If

    Return _Printers

End Function

End Class
```

This bit of code assigns the `List(Of Printer)` to the `ComboBox`:

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)

    _Printer = New Printer

    _Printers = _Printer.Populate(Await GetPrinterList())

    If _Printers.Count > 0 Then
        cbxPrinters.ItemsSource = _Printers
    End If

End Sub
```

When I launch the app and come to this page the code runs OK however I'm left with what looks like 54 blank options to select from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Zaggler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1797425/zaggler) and after investigating the stack trace:

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Id' property not found on 'COACH_HOUSE_SCAN_APP.Printer, COACH HOUSE SCAN APP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

I changed the class slightly so that `Id` and `Name` are now `Properties`:

```
Public Property Id As Integer
Public Property Name As String
```

I have set the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` as suggested by Zaggler:

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)

    _Printer = New Printer

    _Printers = _Printer.Populate(Await GetPrinterList())

    If _Printers.Count > 0 Then
        cbxPrinters.ItemsSource = _Printers
        cbxPrinters.DisplayMemberPath = "Id"
        cbxPrinters.SelectedValuePath = "Name"
    End If

End Sub
```

I also removed this part of the XAML:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="2">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Leaving the XMAL looking like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxPrinters" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Margin="153,150,0,0" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
      Width="237">
</ComboBox>
```

This has fixed my issue and now the printers are now listed in the `ComboBox`.